# Sending local variables into a partial inside of ActiveAdmin isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin page as follows:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Pretty Demo Day" do
  menu label: "Bi-weekly", parent: "Demo Day Statistics"

  this_week = [14.days.ago.to_date..Date.today, "this_week"]
  two_weeks_ago = [28.days.ago.to_date...14.days.ago.to_date, "two_weeks_ago"]
  all_time = [Date.parse("2014-01-01")..Date.today, "all_time"]

  @periods = [this_week, two_weeks_ago, all_time]

  content title: I18n.t("active_admin.demo_day_stats.title") do
    render partial: "admin/shared/demo_day_metrics", locals: { periods: @periods }
  end
end
```

The partial looks like this:

```
%table
  %thead
    %th "Inside the partial"
    - periods.each do |p|
      %th
        - format_period(p)

  %tbody
    - metrics.each do |name, *values|
      %tr
        %td name

        - values.each do |v|
          %td
            - case v
            - when Numeric
              number_with_delimiter(v)
            - when String
              v
            - else
              "N/A"
```

When I try to load up the page, I get the error: `undefined method each for nil:NilClass` on the 4th line, the one containing `periods.each...`

I have inserted a binding.pry into the partial and looked at the local variables.  The variable `periods` is there, but is nil.  I have verified that in the register_page file, @periods has the correct values.

How can I call the partial and send in the set of time periods?  Does ActiveAdmin do something special with partials that is preventing the data from being passed into the partial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't instantiate a variable at that place that you use. The variable must be instantiated in the `content` block.

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Pretty Demo Day" do
  menu label: "Bi-weekly", parent: "Demo Day Statistics"

  content title: I18n.t("active_admin.demo_day_stats.title") do
    this_week = [14.days.ago.to_date..Date.today, "this_week"]
    two_weeks_ago = [28.days.ago.to_date...14.days.ago.to_date, "two_weeks_ago"]
    all_time = [Date.parse("2014-01-01")..Date.today, "all_time"]

    @periods = [this_week, two_weeks_ago, all_time]

    render partial: "admin/shared/demo_day_metrics", locals: { periods: @periods }
  end
end
```